# Usability: mupltiple colored logos for a single site?

Tags: usability, graphical-logo

My client asked me to create a site for our company and sent 5 different logos in 5 different colors. He wants to add different color logo on each page. Say user will open about page then he'll get green color logo, contact page then blue color logo, home will have orange color logo and so on.

Personally I don't want to use multiple logos in this website, but to convince him I need reasons why this is not a good practice.

So, I wanted to know about the usability guidelines for website logo. I googled a lot but didn't able to find such blog post or articles.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the logo doesn't rely on color much and is strong enough to take this kind of beating, then it might actually work.

Anyway, here's a few arguments against changing colors:

- The logo needs to integrate well with the rest of the site to be aesthetically pleasing, so the colors of the stylesheet need to be in synch with the logo. If the logo's colors change, then the rest of the style must follow - this will increase the cost for development and maintenance.
- Maintaining the logos themselves also takes more time - we can't simply make a single template with the logo and a menu; instead, we need 5 dedicated templates, or we need to make the logo part dynamic. Again, increased cost for development and maintenance. Also, if the logo ever needs to change, the graphic designer in charge will have to do the same thing 5 times instead of once.
- Color is one of the most basic things humans recognize, and it has a strong connection with the subconscious. Using one logo and one color set consistently throughout the entire presence leads to a stronger sense of familiarity.
- Changing colors might produce a short moment of confusion to the user, a feeling of accidentally having left the site, a second of "oh, I must have done something wrong" - not good feelings anyway. You don't want to confuse the user, you want a slick, coherent, comfortable, no-surprises experience.

Answer (score 1):

It is more like a marketing question than a usability.
Web site branding needs a permanent visual sign. This is the logo. Permanence means to color also. Changing color page by page strongly confuse visitors.